# How is the Lie algebra obtained from the group in a simple example on a prior post?

Tags: lie-algebras

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2527682/152225) the Lie algebra of the group

$$\left\{\begin{bmatrix}
       x & y \\
       0 & 1 
     \end{bmatrix}\middle|x,y \in \mathbb R, x\neq 0\right\}$$

is immediately given as

$$\left\{\begin{bmatrix}x&y \\ 0&0\end{bmatrix}\,\middle|\,x,y\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$$

I can't find a presentation online with a straightforward example like this including defined steps to follow.

My first inclination would be to find elements in the tangent space at the identity, $$\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

by differentiating the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}
       x & y \\
       0 & 1 
     \end
{bmatrix}$ but I don't know if this is done by parameterizing a curve by $t$ in the plane $x,y$ or there is a need for two parameters. The next step may be evaluating at zero. I don't know; I have never done it. I am just curious.

---

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4374799/152225) should apply here (thank you Professor José Carlos Santos for your correction - any remaining mistake, mine):

Imagining the $x$ and $y$ as functions of a parameter $t$, and defining $\left.\dot x(t)\right|_{t=0} = r$ and $\left.\dot y(t)\right|_{t=0}=s,$

$$\left.\frac d{dt}\begin{bmatrix}x&y\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\right|_{t=0}=\begin{bmatrix}r&s\\0&0\end{bmatrix} \,r, s\in \mathbb R $$

Comment: Your definition of the group was an error in it.

Comment: I agree with @TedShifrin. Some matrices in your "group" are non-invertible.

Comment: @KentaS Was it correct in the linked post?

Comment: This example is worked out in Frankel's book *Geometry of physics* pages 394+. The group is called $A(1)$, the [affine group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_group) on the line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a standard Lie theory theorem:

**Theorem:** If $n\in\Bbb N$ and $G$ is a closed subgroup of $GL_n(\Bbb R)$, then $G$ is a Lie group whose Lie algebra is$$\mathfrak g=\{M\in GL_n(\Bbb R)\mid(\forall t\in\Bbb R):\exp(tM)\in G\}.$$

**Corollary:** If $n\in\Bbb N$, $G$ is a $k$-dimensional Lie subgroup of $GL_n(\Bbb R)$ and $\mathfrak g$ is a $k$-dimensional Lie algebra of $n\times n$ real matrices such that $\exp(\mathfrak g)\subset G$, then $\mathfrak g$ is the Lie algebra of $G$.

**Proof:** Since $\mathfrak g$ is a real vector space, if $t\in\Bbb R$ and $M\in\mathfrak g$, then $tM\in\mathfrak g$, and therefore $\exp(tM)\in G$. So, $\mathfrak g$ is a subalgebra of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak g^\star$ of $G$. But $\dim\mathfrak g=\dim G=\dim\mathfrak g^*$, and therefore $\mathfrak g=\mathfrak g^*$.

---

Now, let$$G=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}x&y\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\,\middle|\, x\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}\wedge y\in\Bbb R\right\}.$$ Clearly, it is a closed subset of $GL_2(\Bbb R)$ and $\dim G=2$. On the other hand, let$$\mathfrak g=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}x&y\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\,\middle|\,x,y\in\Bbb R\right\}.$$Then $\dim\mathfrak g=\dim G=2$ and $\exp(\mathfrak g)\subset G$. Therefore, it follows from the corollary that $\mathfrak g$ is the Lie algebra of $G$.

Comment: The answer seems to prove the Lie algebra is the correct one. But is it found as in the answer that was deleted? Derivative of the matrix wrt $x$ and $y$ to get two matrices,  evaluating at the identity, and figuring out the span?

Comment: That's not how I did it. I looked for the largest Lie subalgebra $\mathfrak g$ of $\mathfrak{gl}_2(\Bbb R)$ such that $\exp(\mathfrak g)$ is a subset of your group.

Comment: Is the $1$ in the lower right corner a typo in $\mathfrak{g}$?

Comment: @Sal Yes. I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: If you don't mind a quick follow-up question, I have tried to follow a simple template from another answer and included it as "show my work" in the original question. Would that make sense, or would it be incorrect or incomplete?

Comment: That is not correct. It should be $\dot x(\color{red}0)=r$ and $\dot y(\color{red}0)=s$.

Comment: Makes total sense - muitos obrigado! I forgot the evaluated at part!